# How do i use typedef in c++ on a function pointer that must return an class template?

Tags: c++

So i have the following code:

```
  typedef Shape *(createShapeFunction)(void);
```

The problem is that shape is a template so i would like it to be something like this:

```
typedef Shape<T> *(createShapeFunction)(void);
```

I have already tried the following

```
typedef template<typename T> Shape<T> *(createShapeFunction)(void);

template<typename T> typedef Shape<T> *(createShapeFunction)(void);
```

It gives me errors saying that this is not allowed.
Can you please help?

Comment: in c++11 `using` should be used instead of `typedef`

Comment: @BryanChen i would use it but i was discouraged to use the new standard so i am trying for less modern methods

Comment: @ciprianr: Don't let them discourage you. C++11 is great!

Comment: `typedef Shape *(createShapeFunction)(void);` means you are declaring a function type which returns a pointer to `Shape`.  The first set of parentheses are redundant. I think you meant for the `*` to be inside the parentheses.

Comment: @ciprianr: Agree with Danvil. The new `using` syntax in C++11 was created to help with problems exactly like yours. And it was added to C++11 exactly because there was no good solution in C++03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
struct ShapeFunctionPointers {
   typedef Shape<T> (*createShape)(void);
};

ShapeFunctionPointers<int>::createShape f;
```

Note that for each type `T` there will be a different function pointer type.

In C++11 you should be able to write:

```
template<typename T> using createShapeFunction = Shape<T> (*)(void);

createShapeFunction<int> f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in C++11

```
template<typename T> using createShapeFunction = Shape<T> (*)(void);
```

does work. That's the cleanest way to do it.